# sed: |: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sed

Alright I am running a function and this is the output I receive:

```
sed: |: No such file or directory
```

four times.

Here are the sed commands ran in the function:

```
sed -i "/${1} {/,/}/d" "$7"
sed -i "s/^${3}/${3}\n\n  ${1} {\n    path \/system\/lib\/soundfx\/boutique\/${4}\n  }/g" "$7"
sed -i "/${8} {/,/}/d" "$7"
sed -i "s/^${6}/${6}\n\n  ${8} {\n    library ${1}\n    uuid ${5}\n  }/g" "$7"
```

I believe the variables are not implemented correctly, after googling and stackoverflowing I added the double quotes and brackets but even that did not correct the issue.

Example input to function:

```
function $DOLSO "$SYSTEM/etc/$AEC" $DOLBYLIBTXT $FILE $DOLBYUUID $DOLBYEFFTXT "$ETC/$AEC" $DOLSO2
```

Variables used in above input:

```
DOLBYLIBTXT="# Dolby Laboratories, Inc. | www.dolby.com | Library"
DOLBYEFFTXT="# Dolby Laboratories, Inc. | www.dolby.com | Effect"
DOLBYUUID=9d4921da-8225-4f29-aefa-39537a04bcaa
DOLSO=ds
DOLSO2=dsplus
FILE=libdseffect.so
SYSTEM=/system
ETC=$SYS/etc
```

and `SYS=/system` or `/system/system` (depends on device)

```
AEC=audio_effects.conf
```

I must add the sed commands work without variables, example:

```
sed -i '/ds {/,/}/d' /system/etc/audio_effects.conf
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a pretty good hunch that you need to double-quote the other arguments in the invocation of your function.

```
function "$DOLSO" "$SYSTEM/etc/$AEC" "$DOLBYLIBTXT" "$FILE" "$DOLBYUUID" "$DOLBYEFFTXT" "$ETC/$AEC" "$DOLSO2"
```

If you don't quote them like this, then you're effectively running

```
function ds "/system/etc/audio_effects.conf" # Dolby Laboratories, Inc. | www.dolby.com | Library libdseffect.so 9d4921da-8225-4f29-aefa-39537a04bcaa # Dolby Laboratories, Inc. | www.dolby.com | Effect "/system/etc/audio_effects.conf" dsplus
```

and if you tabulate the arguments the function receives:

```
$1: ds
$2: /system/etc/audio_effects.conf
$3: #
$4: Dolby
$5: Laboratories,
$6: Inc.
$7: |
$8: www.dolby.com
```

and so on. Quoting your use of "$DOLBYLIBTXT" and so on will fix that.

Comment: You sir deserve an upvote, sadly I cannot give you one :(